# prevent Jsoup from converting utf-8 to utf-16

Tags: utf-8, jsoup, utf-16

I would like the following to return the encoded bullet point the same way it was supplied:

```
Jsoup.parse("<div>&#8226;</div>").text()
```

but instead I get a utf-16 string out with a bullet which displays as a black circle. This is causing rendering problems in Chrome as the rest of the page is utf-8. From the many other SO questions I found I thought this might work

```
Parser.unescapeEntities(Jsoup.parse("<div>&#8226;</div>").text(), true)
```

but in retrospect I see that does the opposite, it turns escaped content into un-escaped.

I found some suggestions that the html needed to claim utf-8 encoding in the head for it to be parsed the way I am hoping, but this valid html is still turning into utf-16

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'><head><title>foo</title><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>
  <body>&#8226;</body>
</html>
```

In particular, I am using Jsoup to parse out an element from previously generated html and return the original html text, such as

```
Jsoup.parse(myHtml).getElementsByClass("myClass").first().toString()
```

Question: how I can I use Jsoup to parse out a fragment of html which contains utf-8 representation of utf-16 characters and not have that content converted to utf-16?

Comment: How do you find it is UTF16? Note: internally JavaScript interpret strings AS IF they are UTF16 (but it doesn't mean it write DOM as UTF16. Maybe you are looking too much on a part which it is not the real problem, but it is difficult to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the text coming out of the first code fragment displays as a bullet, and when I replace that bullet with the original hex value it displays properly in Chrome, and I could see the internal String "coder" property (so 62917183) that indicated 1 (UTF16) when any text containing a hex value was parsed by Jsoup and 0  (LATIN1) when it was not. I have worked around the issue with a horrible hack of removing the hex before parsing and restoring it after parsing and it displays properly in Chrome, now looking for the right way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that this has anything to do with UTF-16. That bullet character is representable in UTF-8. If you are using the decoded form in a page that is served as UTF-8, it will display correctly. I guess there must be another issue with how you are serving it that is dropping to ascii or another encoding.

To directly answer your question: the [`Element.text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()) method **always returns decoded text**.

To get encoded HTML, you should use the [`Element.html()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html()) method. Now, that will default to outputting in UTF-8, and jsoup only escapes characters into entities when the output character set does not support the character, and so the form will be the same. As you seemingly don't want UTF-8 either, you can configure the [OutputSettings](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html) as required.

Here's a worked example:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div>&#8226;</div>");
Element div = doc.expectFirst("div");
print("Text", div.text());
print("HTML Default", div.html());

doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
print("HTML UTF8", div.html());

doc.outputSettings().charset("ascii");
print("HTML ascii", div.html());

doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.extended);
print("HTML extended", div.html());

print("Text", div.text()); // shows that text() is always decoded
```

Gives:

```
Text: •
HTML Default: •
HTML UTF8: •
HTML ascii: &#x2022;
HTML extended: &bull;
Text: •
```

`&#x2022;` is the same as `&8226;`, in [hex vs decimal](https://unicodelookup.com/#0x2022/1) encoding.

(BTW as evidential proof that • can be represented directly in a UTF-8 page, hit View Source for this Stack Overflow page. And Inspect Network to see `Content Type = text/html; charset=utf8`)